# Syntax error with macro array access

Tags: c, arrays, macros, syntax-error

I'm attempting to read values from a 2-dimensional array and multiply them to make a new array array. This isn't entirely important.

I have created a macro to read the values instead of a function to theoretically be more efficient, but I'm having a syntax error that I can't figure out. The line of issue is

```
    // compute and write the value for the result array
        writearr( result, n, r, c, ( READ(r, c, A*) * READ(c, r, A*) ) );
```

with function header

```
    void newarr(int n, int* A, int* result)
```

The macro is

```
    #define READ(a, b, arr) (arr[a][b])
```

and when I try to compile this I get

```
    gcc -Wall -O2   -c -o placeholder.o placeholder.c
    placeholder.c: In function âwritearrâ:
    placeholder.c:26: error: expected expression before â[â token
    make: *** [placeholder.o] Error 1
```

but I can't quite figure out what the issue is.

Comment: "I have created a macro to read the values instead of a function to theoretically be more efficient" That's where you went wrong. Why would you code for theoretical advantages? You should be coding for cleanliness and elegance. When you're *done* you can profile your code, find out where the slow parts are, and fix those. Guessing is worthless.

Comment: Also, you can't index two-dimensionally given just the start and size. You need a width as well, so you can perform arithmetic. See the comments on Vlad's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to enclose your macro arguments in parentheses.

```
#define READ(a, b, arr) ((arr)[a][b])
```

Second, you should use `A` instead of `A*` for dereferencing. `A*` is not valid at all, but you wanted perhaps `&A` (which as actually incorrect as well)?

Third, in this case the macro doesn't actually bring any advantage against just accessing the array.

Fourth, you declared A as a one-dimentional array, you cannot use it as a multidimentional one. Taking an address of a single-dimensional array doesn't allow you to switch to the "next" row automatically, as C++ doesn't know how large the row is going to be.

Comment: Should that not be `READ(r, c, A)`? Dereferencing would just give you an integer; you can't index that. Even then, `(arr)[a]` results in an integer, which cannot be indexed via `b`. The code is broken.

Comment: @GMan: indeed the function signature says that A is a pointer to int, so this code is not valid in any case.

Comment: sorry guys, I misinterpreted the code. A is a two dimensional array stored as a one dimensional array in row major order. thanks.

Comment: @Rowhawn: then your macro should be something like `#define READ(a, b, arr) ((arr)[(a)*N+(b)])`, where `N` is the (constant!) row size. (Or `[(a)+(b)*N])` if your order is opposite.) But an inline function is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using READ macro here. If you have to user this semantics, you need to do:

```
writearr( result, n, r, c, ( READ(r, c, A) * READ(c, r, A) ) );
```